# ImageMagick File is too Big

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm working with imagemagick to convert images from .tiff to .jpeg and make its thumbanils. The converstion from .tiff into .jpeg is OK but the problem comes when I want use imagemagick to move to other folders with others resolutions and creating its thumbnails. Imagemagick says that image in `$path.$destinationPath.$ref.".jpeg"` is too big but that image doesn't exist...

-Here it is my code:

```
exec("/usr/bin/convert ".$tiffPath.$ref.".tiff  ".$CommonPath.$sourcePath.$ref.".jpeg");

// Ok until here

if (!file_exists($CommonPath.$destinationPath.$ref.".jpeg"))
{
    $executa = "/usr/bin/convert -size 800x800 ".$CommonPath.$sourcePath.$ref.".jpeg -thumbnail 800x800 ".$path.$destinationPath.$ref.".jpeg";

    exec($executa);
}
```

Imagemagick returns the following:

```
convert: unable to open image $CommonPath.$destinationPath.$ref.".jpeg": File is too big @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2589.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you using the IMagick PHP wrapper class, and instead are opting for `exec()`?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php

Comment: Hi! @delboy1978uk, I can't install any package ot tool because I'm not the admin of the server

Comment: well tell whoever is in charge of the project that told you to use imagemagick, that you need imagick installed in order to properly deliver the requirements

Answer (score 1):

Your second ImageMagick command is malformed. You have:

```
$executa = "/usr/bin/convert -size 800x800 ".$CommonPath.$sourcePath.$ref.".jpeg -thumbnail 800x800 ".$path.$destinationPath.$ref.".jpeg";
```

The -size 800x800 is for creating a new image via xc: or canvas:. It may be confusing the command line to think you have two input images. It is certainly not needed. Try removing it, such as

```
$executa = "/usr/bin/convert ".$CommonPath.$sourcePath.$ref.".jpeg -thumbnail 800x800 ".$path.$destinationPath.$ref.".jpeg";
```